# Tcolor box Dotted box

Tags: tcolorbox

How to draw dotted box(like rounded dot) in tcolorbox instead of square line boxes, I tried but output shown like square line not rounded dot? Please find my MWE files:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzstyle{dashedboxone}=[dot pattern=on .5pt off 1.2pt]

\tikzstyle{dashedboxone}=[dot pattern=on .5pt off 1.2pt]

\newtcolorbox{BoxTypeA}{%
enhanced,
breakable,
sharp corners,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
boxrule=2pt,boxsep=0pt,top=4pt,left=4pt,right=4pt,bottom=4pt,middle=0pt,
colback=white, 
colframe=white, 
pad at break=0pt,bottomrule at break=0pt,toprule at break=0pt,
borderline east={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
borderline west={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
borderline south={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
borderline north={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
fontupper={\fontsize{9bp}{11bp}\selectfont\ttfamily}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\begin{BoxTypeA}
\# GET reads the keyboard.FIGURE\\
\# READ loads data from a disk file.\\
\# DISPLAY shows output on screen.\\
\# WRITE saves output to a file.\\
DISPLAY “What is your name?”\\
GET UserName\\
OPEN FILE “Users.txt”\\
READ data for UserName\\
IF new data exists THEN\\
WRITE new data to file\\
END IF
\end{BoxTypeA}
\caption{GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard.GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

hm, it seems that you like to have something the following:

[image]

it is obtained by use of `decorations.shapes` tikz library:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\tikzset{
  decoration = {shape backgrounds, shape=circle,
                shape size=0.25pt, shape sep=2pt},
paint/.style = {decorate, fill=black}
}

\newtcolorbox{BoxTypeA}{%
enhanced,
breakable,
sharp corners,
boxrule=2pt,boxsep=0pt,top=4pt,left=4pt,right=4pt,bottom=4pt,middle=0pt,
colback=white,
colframe=white,
pad at break=0pt,bottomrule at break=0pt,toprule at break=0pt,
borderline={0pt}{0pt}{paint},
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t!]
\begin{BoxTypeA}
\# GET reads the keyboard.FIGURE\\
\# READ loads data from a disk file.\\
\# DISPLAY shows output on screen.\\
\# WRITE saves output to a file.\\
DISPLAY “What is your name?”\\
GET UserName\\
OPEN FILE “Users.txt”\\
READ data for UserName\\
IF new data exists THEN\\
WRITE new data to file\\
END IF
\end{BoxTypeA}
\caption{GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard.GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
in case, that you like to have rounded corners of box too, ans use it only in some float environment, than the code can be shorten and modified to the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\tikzset{
  decoration = {shape backgrounds, shape=circle,
                shape size=1pt, shape sep={4pt, between centers}
                },
paint/.style = {decorate, fill=black}
}

\newtcolorbox{BoxTypeA}{%
enhanced,
    boxsep=0mm, left=4pt,
    arc=4pt,
    colback=white,
    colframe=white,%
pad at break=0pt,bottomrule at break=0pt,toprule at break=0pt,
borderline={0pt}{0pt}{paint},
}%

\newtcolorbox{BoxTypeB}{%
enhanced,
sharp corners,
boxrule=2pt,boxsep=0pt,top=4pt,left=4pt,right=4pt,bottom=4pt,middle=0pt,
colback=white,
colframe=white,
borderline={0pt}{0pt}{paint},
}%

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{BoxTypeA}
    \# GET reads the keyboard.FIGURE\\
    \# READ loads data from a disk file.\\
    \# DISPLAY shows output on screen.\\
    \# WRITE saves output to a file.\\
    DISPLAY “What is your name?”\\
    GET UserName\\
    OPEN FILE “Users.txt”\\
    READ data for UserName\\
    IF new data exists THEN\\
    WRITE new data to file\\
    END IF
\end{BoxTypeA}
\caption{GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: which gives]

Comment: Yes I got the required output, Thank you Zarko.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the frame and draw a dotted rectangle with rounded corners:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzstyle{dashedboxone}=[dot pattern=on .5pt off 1.2pt]

\tikzstyle{dashedboxone}=[dot pattern=on .5pt off 1.2pt]

\newtcolorbox{BoxTypeA}{%
enhanced,
breakable,
%sharp corners,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
boxrule=2pt,boxsep=0pt,top=4pt,left=4pt,right=4pt,bottom=4pt,middle=0pt,
colback=white, 
colframe=red, 
frame hidden,
overlay={\draw[dotted, rounded corners=5mm] (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);},
pad at break=0pt,bottomrule at break=0pt,toprule at break=0pt,
%borderline east={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
%borderline west={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
%borderline south={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
%borderline north={0.5pt}{-0.25pt}{black,dotted},
fontupper={\fontsize{9bp}{11bp}\selectfont\ttfamily}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\begin{BoxTypeA}
\# GET reads the keyboard.FIGURE\\
\# READ loads data from a disk file.\\
\# DISPLAY shows output on screen.\\
\# WRITE saves output to a file.\\
DISPLAY “What is your name?”\\
GET UserName\\
OPEN FILE “Users.txt”\\
READ data for UserName\\
IF new data exists THEN\\
WRITE new data to file\\
END IF
\end{BoxTypeA}
\caption{GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard.GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard. GET reads the keyboard.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Visually it looks fine but problem is that while zooming dotted line shown like small square box instead of rounded dot.

Comment: I like it and I vote it positively :-)